# Genymotion doesn't recognize images on sdcard

Tags: android, eclipse, image, virtual-machine, genymotion

So I've been playing with Genymotion. Love using it however haven't been able to figure out how to get images into the Android Gallery app (so i can test another app).  Currently running Android 4.3 on a Galaxy Nexus.

Tried pushing images through adb and through eclipse's file explorer.  The images are copied over fine to /mnt/shell/emulated/0/Pictures.

Any advice? Is it possible to get pictures in Gallery using Genymotion?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
Managed to do it from the browser, however still curious about doing transferring images into Gallery via adb or the file system.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the gallery needs to rescan the folders to index the pictures on the storage. `adb push` does not call the gallery to rescan.

You can launch this broadcast to make the gallery reload its content after you copied your picture:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file:///sdcard/
```

Comment: Worked great. If more than one device connected . Error message will appear like this.
error: more than one device/emulator. Disconnect the device(s) other than emulator.

Comment: Yep. You can also use "-s" option on adb to choose the device you want to run the command on.