# Add folder/files in Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, genymotion

I want to add folder in my `Genymotion emulator`
I also tried this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530114/accessing-files-from-genymotion-sd-card) and follow all instruction but folder is not showing in file manager
I also download some images from [Google](http://www.google.com) but also those not visible in file manager.

In my emulator following file manager installed
    File Managerv 1.0.1
    The CyanogenMod Project

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I solve my problem

First follow this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18532431/2385565)

- Go to your VirtualBox VM setting / Shared folder tab
- Add a shared folder with the folder you want to shared, and check the
  "auto mount" option
- Start your VM as usual from the Genymotion software
- Your shared folder is available in the /mnt/shared directory
  (multiple shared folders are supported)

After that
Change Settings of file Manager in `Genymotion emulator` change that to root user so all my folder visible also with Shared folders

- In Genymotion virtual device, run the application "File Manager" and
  READ the advertisement about "low-privileged mode".
- Go to "settings" menu from "File Manager"
- In "general settings", click on "access mode" and activate "Root
  access" mode
- Restart File Manager => all directories will be presented

Thanks

**Update**
In newer version of `genymotion` you can [add files/folder by drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28790621/2385565).
It take some time while adding files in emulator. time depends on file size.

**Update 2 (Based on @GandhyOnly comment)**

To make visible in gallery just drag and drop your images files on emulator they stored in download folder after finish transferring  files restart same emulator and images will shown in gallery. Or if you don't want to restart emulator  then use following command

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file:///sdcard/
```

it will rescan images and show them in gallery. For more detail about command see the actual answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21636559/2385565). I didn't check command I use first method just restart emulator

Comment: Good job sir. Your solution helps me. :D

Comment: for those who can't find the root access permission in their emulator in android 4.3 : 1- http://goo.gl/ngQm2o  2- restart your emulator

Comment: i already put some image on manage files.. but how to make gallery detect the image ?

Comment: the rescan solution is really useful

Answer (score 40):

Simply **drag and drop** onto the emulator the file that you want to use.

It will be saved in **Download folder**.

Comment: Also to do the vice versa..go to Tools->Android->Android Device Monitor ->Pull your file into the system.

Answer (score 10):

I have a more simpler approach to this .
Open your genymotion , and just

> drag and drop
>   the file in the required directory

I am attaching two screenshots in this regard.I had an app that used pictures, after copying by drag and drop i was able to find pictures in file manager through my app. 
**

> Just drag and drop like following

**
[image]

And you are done
[image]

It will be copied to **Download** Folder

Answer (score 7):

Simply Drag and drop files from your PC to emulator and after copying data, files will be saved in the **DOWNLOAD** folder. Remember that to make **DRAG and DROP** service working, do not open Genemotion Software by **ADMINISTRATOR privileges**.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure whether you're using SD card or not. In case you do, try to look in this folder through DDMS file explorer in Eclipse:

mnt/shell/emulated/0/MyFiles

This is where my files go when using standard SD card reference in my code:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFiles");
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am not using SD Card its just emulator. But Thanks for response.

Comment: The above code can be used for both the real SD Card and emulator SD Card. The address refers to the location of SD Card content on a Genymotion emulator. Just in case someone wants to use it. I hope you sorted your problem. :)

Comment: hmm Thanks :) +1 for general solution